# Why does a TCP SYN scan needs root privilege while a TCP connect doesn't?

Tags: tcp, port-scanning

In TCP SYN scan I understand that we need to manipulate a raw TCP packet(by setting a SYN flag on a raw TCP packet) which requires special or root privileges. But in a TCP full scan we do not need any special privilege? Why is that? I assume even in a TCP full scan you would need to send the TCP packets with flags set. Could anyone please clarify this for me?

Comment: Because raw sockets need root privilege, and stream sockets don't.